# plot in matlab with timer on x axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a Matlab code which plots the variable value against the loop iterations.

I have considered random values as variable value just for this example.

```
function varargout = myplot(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @myplot_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @myplot_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before myplot is made visible.
function myplot_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.output = hObject;
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);


function varargout = myplot_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
axes(handles.axes1);
iif = 0;
i = 1;
y = 0;
while (i < 1000)
    yf = rand(1);
    y = [y, yf];
    iif = [i,iif];
    i = i + 1;
    plot(iif,y);
    pause(0.001);
end
```

How can I replace `iif = [i,iif];` into a timer ?

All I want to have is data plotted against the time(in seconds) instead of data vs loop iterations. Anyone have any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tic`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) and [`toc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html) to keep track of the seconds that have elapsed. `tic` starts the counter and all successive calls to `toc` return the seconds that have elapsed since the last `tic`.

```
iif = 0;
i = 1;
y = 0;

hplot = plot(iif, y);
xlabel('Elapsed Time (s)')
ylabel('Value')

% Force a graphics refresh so that isn't counted in our elapsed time
drawnow

% Start the timer
tic

while (i < 1000)
    yf = rand(1);
    y = cat(2, y, yf);

    % Call toc to get the current elapsed time
    iif = cat(2, iif, toc);

    i = i + 1;

    set(hplot, 'xdata', iif, 'ydata', y);
    pause(0.001)
end
```

[image]

As a side note, you could also write your loop as a for loop and pre-allocate all of your variables which will improve performance.

```
nIterations = 1000;
iif = nan(nIterations, 1);
y = nan(nIterations, 1);

hplot = plot(iif, y);

tic

for k = 1:nIterations
    y(k) = rand(1);
    iif(k) = toc;

    set(hplot, 'XData', iif, 'YData', y)
    pause(0.001)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to replace iif = [toc , iif];

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but its a minimal example of a very large code.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner Understandable. Just remember that re-allocation of data by dynamically expanding an array can be *very* costly especially when you're talking about thousands of iterations.

Comment: I have just realised that It made the performance worst, because of the concatanation i am doing. I am losing 2 seconds there, and its not at all acceptable in the implementation i am doing. I will think about time reducing methods. thanks

Comment: @statisticalbeginner Do you know how many iterations you will be doing? Alternately a common alternative is to expand the matrix to double it's size each time you have to expand it.

Comment: Thanks I will increase the pre-allocation size and I will check.

Comment: Number of iterations varies based on the frequency content of the audio sample. to give an example, a file with 15 sec duration can run for about 400 iterations roughly.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner Yea you can always just initialize to 2000 elements or something higher than what you need. As long as they are NaN, they won't show up in your plots.